# Band of Brothers

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

My grand father has been at the Taj Mahal, the Stari Most and 
the blue Mosque, but still thinks life is a comedy of hell.

My humble servant loves Fawlty Towers,
but behaves like a conquistador.

On which day did the plumber fix the world's biggest hole?

---

Hint 1:

> Luigi is not part of the team!

Hint 2:

> 11 men

Hint 3:

> Jürgen is experiencing tough times after the plumber left him...

Hint 4:

> The servant is now considered to be the best in the world in his role, and number three in general.

Comment: if I don't know what most of these things are, can I still solve the puzzle or do I have to look them all up on wikipedia?

Comment: @user3453281: It is an enigmatic puzzle. Check out http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tags/enigmatic-puzzles/info

Comment: The solution might be related to **coffee**: there is turkish coffee; there is the Dante coffee chain; there is Conquistador coffee in Fawlty Towers ("Conquistador Coffee brings a new meaning to the word vomit").

Comment: After hint 1 (Luigi is not part of the team): Is this puzzle perhaps related to Super Mario?  There **Luigi** is the brother of the **plumber** Mario.

Comment: More random guesses, based on Hint and Hint 3: 11 men perhaps hint at soccer, and Jürgen might be Jürgen Klopp who is currently in big trouble with his team Borusia Dortmund.

Comment: @Gamow you are getting close now... Keep up the good work:-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer must be

> **13 July 2014**
>  (when Germany became soccer world champion against Argentina)

for the following reasons:

> Taj Mahal, Stari Most, blue Mosque -> Mimar Sinan -> Sinan Kurt
>  comedy of hell -> Dante -> Dante Bonfim Costa Santos
>  Fawlty Towers -> the waiter Manuel -> Manuel Neuer
>  behaves like a conquistador -> Pizarro -> Claudio Miguel Pizarro Bosio
>  Plumber -> Super Mario -> Mario Gotze

and:

> band of brothers -> Bayern Munich
>   biggest hole -> biggest goal
>   plumber fixes the world's biggest hole -> Gotze scores against Argentina

Answer (score 7):

I think the date is:

> **September 6, 1522** when Magellan / Elcano completed the first circumnavigation of the earth and provided practical evidence that the earth was not flat.

The Taj Mahal, Stari Most and the blue Mosque are all associated with:

> apprentices of Mimar Sinan who lived during the 1500's

Life is a comedy of hell refers to:

> Dante's Divine Comedy which portrays the earth as a sphere

Fawlty Towers and conquistador refer to:

> the British (I don't know why) and the Spanish (who financed Magellan)

The world's biggest hole is:

> the edge of a flat earth

Comment: not correct. However, you are showing some promising tendencies on some of the hints.